# Extracting specific rows from a larger dataframe using a dataframe containing desired rows

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

This seems like a simple issue but I've been struggling to deal with it and haven't been able to find any answers. I have a CSV file with data for 1000 different soccer teams. I also have a CSV file with the names of a 100 soccer teams whose data I need to extract from the first file. However, I can't seem to find a way to extract the 100 soccer teams' rows from the larger data set and put it into a new data frame. I tried using for loops and seeing if the name of the team in the first file == the name of the team in the second but I keep getting the "levels do not match" error.

The first data file follows the format:

Team Name:  ___________Goals Scored   _________Goals Conceded ......................

the second data file follows the format:

Team Name:

...

Comment: Can you please post an sample of your data and the code you have tried so far? You thing that might help is if you import your data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Then when you use `==`, R will just try to match strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this. Until you put up a sample of your data up (please do read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I'll just assume the names of columns are like this:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame( teams = c( "team1", "team2", "team3" ) )
dataset2 <- data.frame( teams = c( "team2", "team1", "team3" ), goals = c( 4, 1, 2 ) )
```

Then you can do a match function, on the creation of a new column in dataset 1, like so:

```
dataset1$goals <- dataset2$goals[ match( dataset1$teams, dataset2$teams ) ]
```